# YouCompleteMe doesn't show errors when non standard header is included

Tags: c, vim, vim-plugin

When I try include gst.h YCM start innoring all error

For example:

```
#include <math.h>
//#include <gst/gst.h>

main (){ //ycm show error here
int a=0;
int b    //and here
}
```

but

```
#include <math.h>
#include <gst/gst.h>

main (){ //ycm don't show error here
int a=0;
int b    //and here
}
```

path to gst.h included to .ycm_extra_conf.py . What i miss?

Comment: YCM's issue tracker is [over there](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues?state=closed).

Comment: That's not a valid declaration of the `main` function. It *must* return an `int`, and either take two arguments or `void`. So it should look like `int main(void) { ... }`

Comment: I know where errors. I don't know why YCM ignore it.
Thank you for issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

`:YcmDiags` show all warning and error YCM messages.
You must include all nested headers and then YCM parse your code right.
Also you must install `clang` lib correct for C/C++ language.